# How to connect polars write_database with mssql+pyodbc?

Tags: odbc, pyodbc, python-polars

Before `polars>=0.16.10` I was using `.to_pandas().to_sql()` to send a polars dataframe to the database.
Now it should be possible to use the wrapper `pl.Dataframe.write_database()`, however, altough my
`connection_uri` is working for `pl.read_database()` and `pl.read_sql()`. It doesn't work for `pl.Dataframe.write_database()`.

This works:

```
connection_uri = "mssql+pyodbc://username:password@server:port/database"
pl.read_database(query, connection_uri)

# or

pl.read_sql(query, connection_uri)
```

This doesnt:

```
df = pl.Dataframe({...})

df.write_database( 
    table_name='dbo.Mytable',
    connection_uri="mssql+pyodbc://username:password@server:port/database",
    if_exists="append",
    engine="sqlalchemy"
    )

»»» sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

So far I kept using the old method `.to_pandas().to_sql()`, now with the added `.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True).to_sql()` after the latest pandas update.

But I find it quite strange that the same connection_uri string works for read_database but not for write_database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `to_pandas().to_sql()` what parameters are you putting into the `to_sql()`?

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), it would seem you must be feeding it a `sqlalchemy` engine.  Next question, how are you initiating the engine? Is it with the same connection string or is it a different syntax?

The source code of the `pl.DataFrame.write_database` method (the relevant part anyway) is this:

```
try:
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
except ImportError as exc:
    raise ImportError(
        "'sqlalchemy' not found. Install polars with 'pip install polars[sqlalchemy]'."
    ) from exc

engine = create_engine(connection_uri)

# this conversion to pandas as zero-copy
# so we can utilize their sql utils for free
self.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True).to_sql(
    name=table_name, con=engine, if_exists=if_exists, index=False
)
```

So whatever connection string you're using to create the `sqlalchemy` engine you're using for the pandas `to_sql` must work for the polars `write_database` because all it does is use the `pandas` `to_sql`.

Comment: So, the connection I use for `pandas.to_sql()` and `pandas.read_sql()`  is different from the one I use when using polars.read_database() which is based on polars Docs. After trying, like you suggest, to use the same connection str as I use for pandas, it worked! Albeit I have noticed this to be quite significantly slower, in my cases, than the previous .to_pandas().to_sql() without the `use_pyarrow_extension_array=True`